# Can I review disabled Jasmine tests in WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, karma-jasmine

Title says it all, really. When I run tests in WebStorm (Karma & Jasmine) it reports 97/104 tests passed. But it doesn't show me what the 7 were that it skipped. The Show Ignored button on the test results panel doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: How did you disable them? Via iit , xit, or? Provide the corresponding code snippet